# Two-phase authentication using spring security like gmail

Tags: spring-security

I wan't like to implement 2-level authentication like gmail where user need to authenticate using sms sent on mobile (or code sent on mail) apart from username and password.

I am already using spring security 4 in my project. Is there any support with spring security for the same?

Or please let me know the best approach for implementing the same.

Regards,
Jubin